# What would cause Mysql database entries to be truncated to 253 characters?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.1, corruption, truncate

Randomly seeing database entries truncated to 253 characters on a php site and can't figure out why or if it could be malicious or a corruption issue.  Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: What do the column definitions and character set configuration look like?  I'm thinking storing utf-8 data in a latin1 column, perhaps?

Comment: I know historically that inserting a string longer than the size of the field specified in the table definition in MySQL would silently truncate the data and succeed, whereas most normal RDBMSs return an error. What's the table definition you're inserting to? Specifically, what's the column datatype for the field that's being truncated?

Answer (score 2):

If not configured (by adding [`strict_trans_tables`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_strict_trans_tables) to your `sql_mode` settings) to throw errors when presented with invalid data, such as a character value that is longer than the definition of a `VARCHAR` column allows, MySQL truncates it to fit, and only throws a warning.

My guess is that you've got a VARCHAR(255) column and at some point in the process, there's an inconsistency in character set configuration, and you have some UTF-8 characters that at some point in your system are being treated as latin1, causing the system to misinterpret the number of characters and truncate the value.

*Wait, what?  How is the number of "characters" different than the number of "bytes?"*

In UTF-8 encoding, character values from 0x7F (decimal 127) downward are still encoded as their 1-byte ASCII equivalent.  Larger values are encoded as 2 or 3 bytes.  Common symbols like © (ASCII 169 0xA9) and ® (ASCII 174 0xAE) are encoded as two bytes, 0xC2 0xA9 and 0xC2 0xAE respectively.

When fully configured for UTF-8, MySQL understands this; using "®" as an example:

```
mysql> SELECT LENGTH('®'), CHAR_LENGTH('®'), HEX('®');
+--------------+-------------------+-----------+
| LENGTH('®')  | CHAR_LENGTH('®')  | HEX('®')  |
+--------------+-------------------+-----------+
|            2 |                 1 | C2AE      |
+--------------+-------------------+-----------+
```

The `LENGTH()` function returns the number of bytes, while `CHAR_LENGTH()` returns the number of characters.

A `VARCHAR` column restricts *not* the number of storable *bytes* but the number of *characters* you can store in it, regardless of the byte-width of each character... so a VARCHAR(2) column could actually end up containing 6 bytes of data (plus requiring 1 byte of [storage overhead](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/storage-requirements.html)) if the two characters happened to be both 3-byte-wide characters.

However... 0xC2 and 0xAE are both codes for valid characters in the default `latin1` character set, so if you were configured with latin1 but sent those characters in their 2-byte unicode encoding, the server would interpret that single unicode character as if it were two characters -- both valid -- thereby reducing the number of printable characters that could be stored in the VARCHAR(255) column by one character for each 2-byte encoding, or reducing it by two characters for each 3-byte encoding.

In the example above, all of my character_set_* values (except `character_set_filesystem`, which is set to `BINARY`) were set as utf8, and the CHAR_LENGTH() of a 2-byte character was correctly reported as being "1."

Now, I'll change these settings, to illustrate:

```
mysql> set character_set_client = latin1, character_set_results = latin1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select CHAR_LENGTH('®');
+-------------------+
| CHAR_LENGTH('®')  |
+-------------------+
|                 2 |
+-------------------+
```

Note that I didn't actually change anything about my actual client's behavor -- each time the "®" symbol appears, the character was UTF-8 encoded and there were two bytes being sent and received over the wire.  All that changed is that I only told MySQL that what I was sending and what I expected to receive should be interpreted as being sent to the server (`character_set_client`) and returned to me (`character_set_results`) as latin1.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset.html